# RegEx for 15 character alpha-numeric character within JSON

Tags: regex, json, testing, assertion

I am using RegEx to assert the response of an API call, but it's currently a little too 'greedy' and ends up matching all kinds of responses.  The RegEx bits are needed since the actual IDs in the response will be different each time.

The RegEx assertion is this:

```
{data:\[{"name":"Mat","~id":"(.*)"},{"name":"Laurie","~id":"(.*)"}\]},"something":true}
```

Which matches this correct response:

```
{data:[{"name":"Mat","~id":"4fd5ec146fc2ee0fff234234"},{"name":"Laurie","~id":"4fd5ec146fc2ee0fff234227"}]},"something":true}
```

as well as this incorrect response:

```
{data:[{"name":"Mat","~id":"4fd5ec146fc2ee0fff234234"},{"name":"Laurie","~id":"4fd5ec146fc2ee0fff234227"},{"name":"John","~id":"4fd5ec146fc2ee0fff234237"},{"name":"Paul","~id":"4fd5ec146fc2ee0fff234238"},{"name":"George","~id":"4fd5ec146fc2ee0fff234239"}]},"something":true}
```

The second `(.*)` is not just matching the ID of the second item, but it's matching the ID *and* all the other *unwanted* objects.

So I guess I need to make my RegEx be a little more strict when it comes to the `~id` fields.  Since the IDs will always be 24 hex characters, I'd like to replace the `(.*)` with something more appropriate.

- I am writing this in [Go](http://www.golang.org/), and therefore using Go's [RegExp](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) package.
- And am using http://regexpal.com/ to test the RegEx

Comment: Try adding a ? in the sets like so: `(.*?)`

Comment: Thanks Tyler, but it's still too greedy.

Comment: trying using `\S+`? or make something like this: `[\w\d]+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[^"]*`, `[^"]{24}` or `[0-9a-fA-F]{24}` instead of `.*` for your ID fields.

Answer (score 3):

`.` (dot) in regular expression will match anything since a dot in RegEx is a special characteres that matches any single character (exception are newline characters).

You should use this RegEx to match always a 24 hex characters only:

`^[A-Fa-f0-9]{24}$`

Peace